# Execution default-generateModel of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.44.0.Final-redhat-00003:generateModel failed

Tags: drools

I'm trying to build a kjar from an existing drools project after migrating to 7.44.0.Final-redhat-00003 version and relying now on executable rule models.
Without relying on executable rule models (or when setting -DgenerateModel=NO) it was compiling and working well.
Now, I get this error :

```
Failed to execute goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.44.0.Final-redhat-00003:generateModel (default-generateModel) on project controlesnonbloquants-kjar: Execution default-generateModel of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.44.0.Final-redhat-00003:generateModel failed.: CannotConvertException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.44.0.Final-redhat-00003:generateModel (default-generateModel) on project controlesnonbloquants-kjar: Execution default-generateModel of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.44.0.Final-redhat-00003:generateModel failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-generateModel of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.44.0.Final-redhat-00003:generateModel failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.ToMethodCall$CannotConvertException
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.ToMethodCall.convertNameToMethod (ToMethodCall.java:142)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.ToMethodCall.toMethodCallWithClassCheck (ToMethodCall.java:73)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.drlxparse.ConstraintParser.parseFieldAccessExpr (ConstraintParser.java:263)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.drlxparse.ConstraintParser.getDrlxParseResult (ConstraintParser.java:154)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.drlxparse.ConstraintParser.parseBinaryExpr (ConstraintParser.java:331)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.drlxparse.ConstraintParser.getDrlxParseResult (ConstraintParser.java:134)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.drlxparse.ConstraintParser.drlxParse (ConstraintParser.java:102)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.visitor.pattern.PatternDSL.findAllConstraint (PatternDSL.java:136)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.visitor.pattern.PatternDSL.buildPattern (PatternDSL.java:235)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.visitor.ModelGeneratorVisitor.visit (ModelGeneratorVisitor.java:145)
    at org.drools.compiler.lang.descr.PatternDescr.accept (PatternDescr.java:288)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.visitor.AndVisitor.visit (AndVisitor.java:50)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.visitor.ModelGeneratorVisitor.visit (ModelGeneratorVisitor.java:86)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.ModelGenerator.processRule (ModelGenerator.java:186)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.ModelGenerator.generateModel (ModelGenerator.java:159)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.ModelBuilderImpl.compileKnowledgePackages (ModelBuilderImpl.java:281)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.ModelBuilderImpl.buildRules (ModelBuilderImpl.java:209)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.ModelBuilderImpl.postBuild (ModelBuilderImpl.java:129)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build (CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:111)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build (CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:97)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages (AbstractKieProject.java:268)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages (AbstractKieProject.java:216)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify (AbstractKieProject.java:80)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject (KieBuilderImpl.java:279)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll (KieBuilderImpl.java:247)
    at org.kie.maven.plugin.GenerateModelMojo.generateModel (GenerateModelMojo.java:146)
    at org.kie.maven.plugin.GenerateModelMojo.execute (GenerateModelMojo.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

but I have no clue where is/are the error(s)?

Adding debug mode for Maven, I only see in the previous debug logs:

```
Typed expression Input: drlxExpr = this instanceof XxxxYyyyyy , patternType = class x.y.z.Aaaaaa,declarations = []
Typed expression Output:...
```

Any idea to find out what is wrong?

I would like to show here the rule(s) that is(are) causing problems but I don't know which one and I have hundreds of them.
Eventually I may have found what is causing the issue. Here is a light version of the rule:

```
rule "CSE1.001_CCR-00141"
when
    $elementA : PeriodX(
    )

    $elementB : PeriodX(
            this != $elementA,
            toCheck || $elementA.toCheck
    )
then
    insert (HelperAction.buildError("CSE1_001_CCR_00141", $elementA, $elementB));           
end
```

It seems that $elementA.toCheck is causing the issue. If I toCheck is a boolean field, if I add "$elementA.toCheck==true" it then compiles.

Thank you

Comment: This is impossible to debug without you sharing the rules and/or full mvn log.

Comment: @AntonGiertli I have just added the full maven log. I could add the failing rule if I had a clue about the one that is causing problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm one of the Drools developers

It's a problem with the compilation of the new evaluation engine of Drools which is the default since 7.39, [the executable model](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.46.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#executable-model-upgrading-proc_packaging-deploying). Please provide the failing rule so that we can fix it.

Edit:

Here's the JIRA created to track it

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-5852

Thanks for helping us improving Drools!

Comment: I have just added full maven log. I'd love to provide the failing rule but since there is no log about the error. How can I find out the rule?

Comment: @BenjaminC as this task was solved, can you mark the answer as accepted? Thank you!

Comment: Hey Luca, I'm getting a similar-ish error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.43.0.Final:generateModel (default-generateModel) on project project_name: Execution default-generateModel of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.43.0.Final:generateModel failed: The given method 'public final java.lang.String com.somepackage.AClassName.getId()' is not from a RuleUnit instance -> [Help 1]


Could it be related to this Stack overflow error as well?

Comment: @Multiplexor it's probably something else, please take a look at the created JIRA and file one similar so that we can take a look at it. Thank you!

Comment: @LucaMolteni Late reply on my side, but we found the error to be that the filename could not be the same name as the model name we were using.

Comment: Thanks @Multiplexor please create a separate JIRA as well